# Linq OrderByDescending ThenByDescending Issue

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

Hi im having a problem with ordering with linq.
I have a object with two datetime fields. One just stores the date (e.g. 8/2/2010) and leaves the time as all 0's

While the other datetime field is created when the record is made and has the time on it as well. The idea of these two field are because I may want to add a "Headline/article" that is a couple days old to my site. So the first Datetime called "Date" is the one I pick, Generally this is defaulted to todays date.

Problem I have is I can order by The date but if I have a number of articles added on the same date (so in the datebase their date field are all identical) the newest article is put to the bottom of the three!

Example:
Article1 - 12/08/2010 - 12/08/2010 2:45pm
Article2 - 12/08/2010 - 12/08/2010 3:45pm
Article3 - 12/08/2010 - 12/08/2010 4:45pm
Article4 - 11/08/2010 - 12/08/2010 2:50pm

they seem to only order by the date field and not date field then created date field which I assumed they should when I use the command (as their date fields are identical)

```
HeadlineRepository.All().OrderByDescending(x => x.Date).ThenByDescending(x => x.Created).Take(8)
```

Bit at a lose here tried to swap them both around but doesn't produce the result I want. seems that it just ignores the thenbydescending...

Steve

*EDITED*

Ok some more information for you all

```
Headlines = repository.All().OrderByDescending(x => x.Date).ThenByDescending(x => x.Created)
```

Produces (Date then Created displayed)

10/08/2010 00:00:00 10/08/2010 19:27:46

10/08/2010 00:00:00 10/08/2010 19:27:21

09/08/2010 00:00:00 10/08/2010 21:28:11

09/08/2010 00:00:00 09/08/2010 00:00:00

While Gives

```
Headlines = repository.All().OrderByDescending(x => x.Created).ThenByDescending(x => x.Date),
```

09/08/2010 00:00:00 10/08/2010 21:28:11

10/08/2010 00:00:00 10/08/2010 19:27:46

10/08/2010 00:00:00 10/08/2010 19:27:21

09/08/2010 00:00:00 09/08/2010 00:00:00

Comment: Any luck trying `HeadlineRepository.All().OrderByDescending(x => x.Date.Date).ThenByDescending(x => x.Created).Take(8)`?

Comment: What order does this code produce from your example set?

Comment: Your code sample doesn't assign the result of the expression to a variable. You're not expecting those methods to have side effects on your original collection are you?

Comment: ive updated the article to give better examples!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears your logic is correct. I've reproduced your scenario in a console app at http://pastebin.org/467317

Using this statement produces the results you were expecting.

```
reg.OrderByDescending(x=>x.RegisteredOn)
   .ThenByDescending(x=>x.StartsClassOn)
   .Take(8)
```

Are you assigning the LINQ query to a variable or ensuring somehow that it's executed as you expect?

[image]