# Variable OrderBy in Controller

Tags: asp.net, controller, sql-order-by

I have code similar to this in my controller which is working successfully,
     var results = from c in dbContext.MyClass
                          orderby c.EnrtyDate descending
                          select c;
     return View(results.ToList());

Now the user would like to select the field(s) to OrderBy.  I have 5 dropdown lists each of which contains the same 5 field name choices.  The user can select the first field to order by from the first dropdown list, then the second from the second dropdown list, etc. up to a total of five fields; let's call the value of the first selection sort1, the second sort2, then sort3, sort4, and sort5.

I need to make the orderby reflect the choices the user has made, e.g.,
                          orderby sort1, sort2, sort3, sort4, sort5
How do I reference this fields in the orderby since they are variables containing the field names, not the actual field names themselves?  I cannot code for all of the hundreds of possible combinations individually.

Comment: It usually helps to include a short example of what you're working with so that users can easily help. Keep that in mind for future questions (or to consider improving this one).

Comment: maybe this answer could help to you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41244/dynamic-linq-orderby-on-ienumerablet

Answer (score 0):

You can nest order bys. You call the `OrderBy` for the main sort if you are sorting in an ascending manner and `OrderByDescending` if you are sorting in a descending manner. The nested sort, for sort two has to use `ThenBy` if it is ascending or `ThenByDescending` if it is descending. Basically, `ThenBy` and `ThenByDescending` will do exactly what you wanted.

Read more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3453278/linq-orderbydescending-thenbydescending-issue) and [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/baf47c50-24c2-4459-97fe-3912b979d32f/orderby-and-thenby?forum=linqprojectgeneral).